# How to save StringGrid content in MySql database in one column?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

This code gets the StringGrid contents per row with `'|'` as a separator.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.datas();
var
  iRow: integer;
  RowData : string;
begin  
  {get stringgrid content}
  for iRow := 1 to Form7.StringGrid1.RowCount -1 do  // count rows
  begin
    RowData := Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[0, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[1, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[2, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[3, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[4, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[5, iRow] + '|';
     
    names := RowData; // it only get the last row in string grid :(
  end;
end;
```

This code is for saving the data to the database:

```pascal
{SAVE}
procedure TForm1.SaveBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin                                                
  datas; // get data
  with SQLQuery4 do
  begin
    if RecordCount = 0 then
    begin
      close;
      SQL.Text := 'Insert into my_db(names) values(:names)';
      Params.ParamByName('names').AsString := names;
    
      ExecSQL;
      SQLTransaction4.Commit;
      Close;
      ShowMessage('Records Successfully Saved!');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I want to save all of the StringGrid rows into one database column, but it only saves the data of the last row :(

I want to save it like this in my DB column:

```
A|B|C|D|E|  // first row
F|G|H|I|J|  // second row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `datas()` method, each loop iteration is *overwriting* the value of `names` with just the current row's data. That is why you are saving only the last row assigned to `names`.  You need to instead *append* each row to `names`, *preserving* its existing data, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.datas();
var
  iRow: integer;
  RowData : string;
begin  
  names := ''; // <-- RESET THE STRING HERE
  {get stringgrid content}
  for iRow := 1 to Form7.StringGrid1.RowCount -1 do  // count rows
  begin
    RowData := Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[0, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[1, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[2, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[3, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[4, iRow] + '|' + Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[5, iRow] + '|' + sLineBreak;
     
    names := names + RowData; // <-- APPEND, NOT OVERWRITE!
  end;
end;
```

Though, I would probably re-write it to something more like this to clean it up a little:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.datas();
var
  iRow, iCol: integer;
  Grid: TStringGrid;
begin  
  names := '';
  {get stringgrid content}
  Grid := Form7.StringGrid1;
  for iRow := Grid.FixedRows to Grid.RowCount-1 do  // count rows
  begin
    for iCol := Grid.FixedCols to Grid.ColCount-1 do // count colums
    begin
      names := names + Grid.Cells[iCol, iRow] + '|';
    end;
    names := names + sLineBreak;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  :) Now my other problem is retrieving data from database to stringGrid, by splitting data per column by  '| ' and put it per row..

Comment: There are many different ways you could handle that - 1) `Pos()` and `Copy()`, 2) `StrUtils.SplitString()`, 3) `SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split()`, 4) `TStringList.DelimitedText`, 5) a combination of the above

Comment: I can get the data by doing `Form7.StringGrid1.Cells[0, Form7.StringGrid1.RowCount-1] := (names.split('|')[0]);` but I don't know how to put in a loop so that it will get data for each row...

Comment: @NewbieKid Please ask a new question for this problem.

Comment: @NewbieKid Since you are concatenating all of the grid's rows and columns into a single string in the db, you are going to have to split that db string into rows using `sLineBreak` as the delimiter, and then split each row into columns using `|` as the delimiter. `split()` returns an array, save it to a local variable, and then loop through it as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I posted a new question about this problem, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962267/retrieve-values-from-database-to-stringgrid]